# How to rename a text file using an integer variable in Python?

Tags: python

I want to rename a file xyz.txt to 1.txt. Consider 1 as an integer variable in 1.txt.

I have tried os.rename(old name, new name). But in the new name, I want to pass my integer variable + ".txt"

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
i = 1
new_name = str(i) + ".txt"
os.rename(old_name, new_name)
```